# How to sum object times and create total?

Tags: java, time, invoke

The purpose of this program is to prompt the user to enter activity times which prints the running total and eventually returns the total time in minutes and seconds once the user decides to end the application. The issue I'm having is understanding how to add the totalTime with activityTime by invoking the addTime method on a type Itime object.

> Driver Class

```
public class ActivityManager
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Itime totalTime, activityTime; // declare totalTime and activityTime of type Itime
    int minutes; double seconds; // user input values
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); // to read user input

    // display purpose and author
    System.out.println ("This program tracks total time in minutes");  
    System.out.println ("and seconds for a series of activities."); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line 

    // specify format for input 
    System.out.println ("Enter activity time in minutes and" 
        + " seconds, all in a");   
    System.out.println ("single line with spaces in between.  Entering" 
        + " values" ); 
    System.out.println ("outside appropriate ranges will terminate"
        + " the program."); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line

    // create the totalTime object of type Itime with 0 minutes and 0.0 seconds
    totalTime = new Itime (0,0.0);
    System.out.println ("Total time so far is: "
        + totalTime.toString()); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line

    // prompt and read time for an activity 
    System.out.print ("Enter time for an activity: "); 
    minutes = input.nextInt(); 
    seconds = input.nextDouble();

    // Accumulate if appropriate 
    while (minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0 && seconds < 60) {
        // create the activityTime object of type Itime with given minutes and seconds
        activityTime = new Itime (minutes, seconds);
        // add totalTime and activityTime and put the result in totalTime
        totalTime = totalTime.addTime(activityTime);
        System.out.println ("Total time so far is: " + totalTime.toString()); 
        System.out.println ();  // print blank line

        // prompt and read time for another activity
        System.out.print ("Enter time for an activity: ");   
        minutes = input.nextInt(); 
        seconds = input.nextDouble(); 
    }

    // wrap up and print final total
    System.out.println ("Sentinel received"); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line 
    System.out.println ("Total time so far is: "
                        + totalTime.toString()); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line

    // print closing remarks
    System.out.println ("Program has terminated."); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line 
}
```

}

> Main Class

```
public class Itime
{
private int minutes;
private double seconds;
/**
 * Constructer objects of class Itime
 */
public Itime (int minutes, double seconds)
{
    assert minutes >=0;
    assert seconds >=0 && seconds <60;

}
/**
 * Getter methods
 */
public int getMinutes()     { return this.minutes; }
public double getSeconds()  { return this.seconds; }

/**
 * Method to return time in String format
 */
public String toString ()
{
    String toString = minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds";
    return toString;
}

**public addTime (pass Itime objects as params here)**
{

}

}
```

Comment: Tip: use the built-in `Duration` class for amounts of time.

Comment: Tip: Declaring all your local variavles at the top of your method is a style from the 1970s and earlier. In Java move each declaration to where the variable is being initialized and do both on the same line. Example: `Itime totalTime = new Itime(0, 0.0);`. For `activityTime` this means moving the declaration inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public Itime addTime(Itime itime) {
    this.minutes = this.minutes + itime.getMinutes();
    this.seconds = this.seconds + itime.getSeconds();
    if (this.seconds > 60) {
      this.seconds = this.seconds % 60;
      this.minutes++;
    }
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Duration class from java.time

Java has a built-in class for an amount of time: `Duration`. So you are really trying to reinvent the wheel. I suggest that you don’t do that. Here’s what your `Itime` class may look like when using `Duration` for implementation:

```
public class Itime {
    private static final double NANOS_PER_SECOND = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1);

    private final Duration dur;

    /**
     * Constructer objects of class Itime
     */
    public Itime(int minutes, double seconds) {
        if (minutes < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("minutes must be >= 0");
        }
        if (seconds < 0 || seconds >= 60) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("seconds must be >= 0 and < 60");
        }
        dur = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes).plus(Duration.ofNanos(Math.round(seconds * NANOS_PER_SECOND)));
    }

    private Itime(Duration dur) {
        this.dur = dur;
    }

    // Getter methods

    public int getMinutes() {
        return Math.toIntExact(dur.toMinutes());
    }

    public double getSeconds() {
        return dur.toSecondsPart() + dur.toNanosPart() / NANOS_PER_SECOND;
    }

    /**
     * @return time in String format
     */
    public String toString() {
        String toString = getMinutes() + " minutes and " + getSeconds() + " seconds";
        return toString;
    }

    public Itime addTime(Itime other) {
        return new Itime(dur.plus(other.dur));
    }

}
```

Your `addTime` method has become a one-liner using a second constructor I introduced for the purpose. The `Duration` class takes care of all time math. This is a good thing because it’s a bit tedious to write and easy to get wrong.

With this implementation here’s an excerpt from a run of your driver class:

```
Enter time for an activity: 91 43.21
Total time so far is: 91 minutes and 43.21 seconds

Enter time for an activity: 12 20
Total time so far is: 104 minutes and 3.21 seconds

Enter time for an activity: -1 -1
Sentinel received
```

Points to note:

- Since `Duration` doesn’t directly accept or give us seconds as a `double`, I unfortunately had to put in a little math in the constructor and the `getSeconds` method.
- I declared the `dur` field `final` becuase I saw no need for being able to modify it (you may similarly declare the two fields in your implementation `final`).
- Using `assert` for validating arguments in a `public` constructor is considered poor style. Instead I use `if` and throw an appropriate `IllegalArgumentException`. (But argument validation is good; `assert` is better than nothing.)
- Since we need to pass an `Itime` to the `addTime` method and get an `Itime` back from it. the method must be declared with one parameter of type `Itime` and with return type `Itime`: `public Itime addTime(Itime other)`.

### Alternative design: drop Duration in instead of Itime

In the above design `Itime` has effectivly become a wrapper around a `Duration`. This design has its pros and cons. Instead you may drop your `Itime` class completely and use `Duration` directly. Pros:

- Simpler design, one class fewer.
- You may modify the user input to a format that `Duration.parse` would parse for you. Then we would no longer need any math for converting the `double` into something that `Duration` understands.

Con:

- Your program seems designed around your `Itime` class, and on a few points `Duration` will not be so good a fit. Specifically you would probably want to write an auxiliary method for converting a `Duraiton` into a string like `177 minutes and 30.0 seconds`.

### Links

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See in particular the section [Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html).